# Mapping Lookup field with the variable in the Odata Query URL using Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, dynamics-crm, lookup

Since Web API is to new to almost everyone, I am also one among them.

The below is the piece of code where the function contains only the
server url and odata query.

I am getting error while while mapping _new_technology_value (lookup field) in 
the odata query.

I tried so many possibilities but failed to get the correct way to map it.

```html
function calculate() {
    debugger;
    var role = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_role").getValue(); //optionset

    //lookup field

    var tech = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_technology").getValue(); 
    var techid = tech[0].id; 

    if (role == 1) {
        debugger;
        var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
        var OdataURL = serverUrl + "/api/data/v8.0/new_technologyusermappings$select=new_name,new_role,_new_technology_value&$filter=new_role eq " + role + " and **_new_technology_value eq '"+techid+"'**";
        getRecords(OdataURL);
    }

}
```

Note:

1. 1 denotes the option set value.
2. Highlighted words is the place of the query where I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried enclosing the lookup Guid in Quotes("") and apostrophe('') but did't work.
Finally got success when I didn't enclose the lookup Guid in Quotes("") or apostrophe('')

e.g replace

```
" and _new_technology_value eq '"+techid+"'";
```

BY

```
" and _new_technology_value eq "+techid;
```